# Javascript checking @ in email

Tags: javascript, html, function, email, input

I am trying to check an HTML input form to see if it contains an @ symbol.

HTML:

```
    <input id="emailCheck" type="text" name="uid" />
    <input type="button" value="Continue" onClick="continuePlease()" />
    <br>
    <p id="invalidEmail"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var at = document.getElementById("emailCheck").value.indexOf("@");

function continuePlease() {
    if (at == -1) {
    document.getElementById("invalidEmail").innerHTML = "<font color=red>Please enter a valid email.</font>";
    } else {
    changeData();
    }
}

function changeData() {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "<font color=#33FF00> Information Confirmed </font>";
    document.getElementById("lock").innerHTML = "<font color=red>This Account is now locked.</font>";
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<font color=white> You will have 30 minutes to send the provided wallet address the correct amount of Bitcoin or the account will unlock again. </font>";                  
    document.getElementById("daemon").innerHTML = "<font color=white> Our Bit-Daemon is watching the address 24/7, once a payment is made, the contents of the  account will be sent to your Email. Thanks, Paypal Trader.</font>";
    document.getElementById("pig").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("cow").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("invalidEmail").innerHTML = "<font color=red>Please enter a valid email.</font>";
}
```

What's happening is that when it performs the function continuePlease() it does both the code in the IF and in the ELSE.
It should do one or the other, not both.

I think I need a better way to check for the @ symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `at` assignment as the first line of the `continuePlease`. I don t think it is doing both it is always doing the else block and check the last line of the else block it is same with if block.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's always some stupid mistake like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this handy function to test that:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

You can pass in the email using this:

`var email = document.getElementById("email").value;`

This function will return either true or false depending on the email string you'll provide.

Comment: Would I replace "email" with the id of my text input field?

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's problem though, this just checks email using a different method.

Comment: Simply checking that `@` exists in a string isn't enough. I just provided a better way to check for a valid email.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way. It should work.

```
function continuePlease() {
    var at = document.getElementById("emailCheck").value.indexOf("@");

    if (at == -1) {
       document.getElementById("invalidEmail").innerHTML = "<font color=red>Please enter a valid email.</font>";
    } else {
       changeData();
    }
}
```